# Using null value in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a database table: `Employee` with fields `id`, `name`, `sex`, `age`.

I run the following queries, and they gave different results. So what's the difference between them?

```
SELECT name, sex
FROM Employee
WHERE age = null
```

or

```
SELECT name, sex
FROM Employee
WHERE age is null
```

Comment: Any comparison to `NULL` returns `NULL` (which is treated as false) except for `IS NOT NULL` and `IS NULL`.

Comment: The diff is the 2nd one works

Comment: I think the question may be database specific.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL there's three-valued-logic, TRUE/FALSE/UNKNOWN. Any comparison to NULL results in UNKNOWN, both following queries will **always** return an empty result set regardless if there are NULLs in `age`:

```
select name,sex
from employee 
where age=null;

select name,sex
from employee 
where age<>null;
```

To get the correct result you need either `where age IS NULL;` for employees with **unknown** age or `where age IS NOT NULL;` for all employees with **known** age.